# Question about the proof of "If K is a compact set of the metric space Ω, then K is closed"

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, compactness

I am reading the proof of the Theorem: If $K$ is a compact set of the metric space $\Omega$, then $K$ is closed, and I encounter a problem.
Here is the proof in the book

[image]

What I don't understand is the last sentence. Why when $K$ belongs to $G_s$ for some $s$, and it follows that $B_{1/s}(x)$ belongs to $K$'s complement.

Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: You have a finite subcover, so $K $ is contained in some finite union of the $G $s, but the increasing property means that such a union is just $G_m $ where $m $ is the largest index in the finite subcover.

Comment: This seems a bit overkill though. An easier proof: take a convergent sequence, it has a convergent subsequence whose limit is in the set, but that limit must be the same as the original limit, so the limit is in $K $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $K\subseteq G_s$, and let $y\in K$. Then $y\in G_s$, so by definition $d(x,y)>\frac1s$. That is, all points of $K$ are *more* than $\frac1s$ units distant from $x$. If $u\in B\left(x,\frac1s\right)$, however, then $d(x,u)<\frac1s$: all points of $B\left(x,\frac1s\right)$ are *less* than $\frac1s$ units distant from $x$.. Thus, no member of $B\left(x,\frac1s\right)$ can belong to $K$, and it follows that they all belong to the complement of $K$: $B\left(x,\frac1s\right)\subseteq K^c$.

Comment: Thank you! And I also have anther question is that "If x is not equal to y, then d(x, y) > 1/m for some m" But the definition of distance only states that "If x is not equal to y, d(x, y) > 0." Are those two statements the same?

Comment: @Chen: You’re welcome! Yes, they are the same: if $r$ is a real number, and $r>0$, then there is a positive integer $m$ such that $r>\frac1m$. (Equivalently, $m>\frac1r$.) This is the [Archimedean property](http://planetmath.org/archimedeanproperty) of $\Bbb R$.